# Override typo in multiple parent theme files?

Tags: filters, child-theme, parent-theme

I'm using the lovely [Imbalance](http://wpshower.com/themes/imbalance/) theme from WPShower. I am able to make almost all the modifications I need through files and filters in the child theme I created.  However, there is a typo that appears in multiple files:

```
<?php printf(__('<span>Filled under:</span> %s'), get_the_category_list(', ')); ?><br />
```

This line is in archive.php. attachement.php, archive.php, and single.php.  Is there a way to change "Filled under" to something like "tags" without directly editing the parent theme files?

Thanks!

Comment: The theme doesn't even use a text domain. Not so lovely …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override it, but you'll have to create Child-Theme versions of `archive.php`, `attachment.php`, and `single.php`.

Since it's a translation string, you might be able to do something hackish, like provide a en_US.MO file that translates "Filled under" as "Filed under" (or whatever you want). But that gets tricky - and This Theme appears to be `_doing_it_wrong()`, putting HTML tags inside of `__()`. So I'm not sure I'd even want to start messing with translation files.

The best solution would be to report the incorrect string as a **bug**, directly to the developer.

Comment: Thanks so much, I reported it as a bug already.  I'll go ahead and add those 4 files to my child theme.  Just seems unnecessarily bulky!